# Getting Ubuntu to work on Thinkpad E145

Tags: drivers, brightness, thinkpad

tl;dr at the bottom

I just bought a brand new Lenovo Thinkpad E145, without any pre-installed OS. I wanted to get an Ubuntu distribution so i can run gnuplot and similar stuff, just things for university mostly.

I tried different distributions (to be exactly: Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Linux Mint and OpenSUSE) but none of them worked correctly.

The most basic things work perfectly, but i cant use the Fn-Keys to adjust anything. The only working Fn-Key is the one for the Wifi (the ones for brightness just show a brightness-bar, but nothing actually changes). On Mint at least the volume keys worked, but the brightness did'nt work either.

Now I can't even change the brightness in the systemsettings, so i guess its a driver related problem (I'm new to OS-related problems so i could be wrong).

**tl;dr:** My Question is: Has anyone got a working version of a distribution on their Lenovo Thinkpad E145? If so, then did you need to do "special things" to get it to work?

I would appreciate any help, as i want to use the laptop with Linux, not rely on Windows for my work.

Greetings, Paul

p.s.: I'm no native speaker, you can correct my English if you want :)